# Midi keyboard problem: some notes trigger two different notes

Tags: midi-controller-keyboard

I've been loking for hours without succses a solution  for this problem:

- My new midi keyboard: Nektar Impact 25 when I play some notes, as F, it triggers F & G at the same time, this problem keeps ocuring with different octaves, even differents DAWS: Logic and cubase,

I tried to reset to factory settings, not working tho,

I bought the same keyboard for my borther at the same time and don't have this issues,

Thanks in advance if u know the soulution, kind regards!

Answer (score 5):

The solution to this problem is to send your Midi keyboard back and buy a new one. It is faulty. The common denominator here is your keyboard's hardware. Not the settings, not the DAW. The keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

I have an Oxygen 25 keyboard and it did the same. I looked on several forums and a guy on a Steinberg forum said he opened it up and unplugged the display board connector, which also has the modulation wheel run through it. I did it and now every key is separated, I just can't see lights and no wheel, but it plays perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it sounds like you got a bad keyboard. I have heard of this problem with rubber pad controllers, where one pad is struck and the pad next to it triggers also. Does it happen no matter how hard you press a key? If so, you might mess with the velocity sensitivity and play with a lighter touch, but it shouldn't be happening at all.